# Store whole model class members in session

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

In a newly created MVC4 application, I would like to store all the USERProfile members in a session such that I can access all the values after the user logs in. But Session array object only proposes 2 alternative

`Session[int]/Session[string]`

I need to retrieve

`Session['username']; Session['age']; etc`

anything existing in that class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can store

```
Session["UserProfile"]=UserProfile; // User Profile being an object
```

The caveat, is when you retrieve your profile you must cast it:

```
UserProfile profile = (UserProfile) Session["UserProfile"]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you listed are the keys that can be used to access something in session.  A key can either be an int or a string.

Simply do

```
Session.Add("MyProfile", USERProfileObject);
```

and you can store that whole object in session.

Note that : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.add.aspx

shows that it takes a string and an object.